# how to limit the number of simultaneous processes?

Tags: linux, php, ubuntu, process

I have an ubuntu server and I am using it for cpu heavy verifications. I want to limit the number of simultaneous verifications to 10. Is there an easy way to limit the process called "vis" to being able run only 10 of them at the same time?

Comment: Sounds like an application specific question, rather than OS.  Should be some sort of config for it.

Comment: How are they being launched?

Comment: @Brian : i know how to do it in application, I was just looking for an easier solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ulimit is the command to make these types of restrictions.
I would recommend you make a user called `visuser` and add the following line to the .bashrc file:

```
ulimit -u 10
```

You might have to make it 11 though to make up for the shell.